# problem in connecting two device through socket programming in python

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to send a simple message from my mobile to my laptop through socket programming in python. I'm using `win 10` and `python 3.7.4` on my laptop. I am also running `python 3.9.0` on `termux` .

and the laptop is connected to cellphone's hotspot.

my server.py is:

```
import threading
import os

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.accept_connections()
    
    def accept_connections(self):
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        port = int(input('Enter desired port --> '))

        self.s.bind((ip,port))
        self.s.listen(100)

        print('Running on IP: '+ip)
        print('Running on port: '+str(port))

        while 1:
            c, addr = self.s.accept()
            print(c)
            
            threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client,args=(c,addr,)).start()

    def handle_client(self,c,addr):
        data = c.recv(1024).decode()
    
        if not os.path.exists(data):
            c.send("file-doesn't-exist".encode())

        else:
            c.send("file-exists".encode())
            print('Sending',data)
            if data != '':
                file = open(data,'rb')
                data = file.read(1024)
                while data:
                    c.send(data)
                    data = file.read(1024)

                c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                c.close()
                

server = Server()
```

and my client.py is:

```
import socket
import os

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect_to_server()

    def connect_to_server(self):
        self.target_ip = input('Enter ip --> ')
        self.target_port = input('Enter port --> ')

        self.s.connect((self.target_ip,int(self.target_port)))

        self.main()

    def reconnect(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.connect((self.target_ip,int(self.target_port)))

    def main(self):
        while 1:
            file_name = input('Enter file name on server --> ')
            self.s.send(file_name.encode())

            confirmation = self.s.recv(1024)
            if confirmation.decode() == "file-doesn't-exist":
                print("File doesn't exist on server.")

                self.s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                self.s.close()
                self.reconnect()

            else:        
                write_name = 'from_server '+file_name
                if os.path.exists(write_name): os.remove(write_name)

                with open(write_name,'wb') as file:
                    while 1:
                        data = self.s.recv(1024)

                        if not data:
                            break

                        file.write(data)

                print(file_name,'successfully downloaded.')

                self.s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                self.s.close()
                self.reconnect()
                
client = Client()
```

my problem is that when I run the `server.py` on the cellphone and `client.py` on laptop, I get
`ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

and when I run `server.py` on laptop and `client.py` on cellphone, I get `TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`

***there is no antivir on laptop and windows defender is deactive

*** I have not installed any kind of network security software on my cellphone neither (but I'm not sure whether there is any kind of preinstalled application)

*** also my firewall is disabled.

Comment: @fireball.1 tnx for your comment, my fire wall is disabled and I'm not using port 100. I'm using something random like ```12345``` or ```8080```

Answer (score 0):

if you doing this over the internet not local you need to open the router port